# How to clear ng-select selection

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

Is it possible to programmatically clear the selection of an ng-select dropdown? I'm wanting the equivalent behaviour of clicking the clear icon, but triggered programmatically.

[image: Screenshot of ng-select dropdown, with clear icon circled in red]

I was expecting a `clear()` method or something similar, but the [documented API](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#methods) doesn't have anything along those lines.

This is my dropdown code:

```
<ng-select class="ng-select-wrap"
           [searchFn]="multiTermSearch"
           [items]="calculationOptions"
           placeholder="Please select..."
           name="calculation"
           #calculationValue="ngModel"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCalculation">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here is solution from comment:

```
  // Access ng-select
  @ViewChild(NgSelectComponent) ngSelectComponent: NgSelectComponent;

  // Call to clear
  this.ngSelectComponent.handleClearClick();
```

Note that `handleClearClick` isn't exposed in docs as public api method however as **Tim** mentioned it's public method so it's possible to call it.

Comment: This causes focus on selected input.

Comment: `this.ngSelectComponent.clearModel();`, this works for me.

Comment: I have multiple instance of ng-select. How to detect and clear a particular one ?

Comment: @GSangram then you should use `@ViewChildren` and find your particular one.

Comment: @GSangram you can still use `@ViewChild` if you're just selecting one.  For instance, `@ViewChild(NgSelectComponent) autocompleteField: NgSelectComponent;` will select for an element tagged like this in your template: `<ng-select #autocompleteField></ng-select>`.  Add whichever other properties you're using on your select already, just add ensure there's a key hash with a name matching the declared variable name in the component.

Answer (score 13):

I was looking for the same but for templates to invoke it outside `ng-select`. So, the below worked fine for me following the accepted answer. ^_^

```
<ng-select class="ng-select-wrap"
           [searchFn]="multiTermSearch"
           [items]="calculationOptions"
           placeholder="Please select..."
           name="calculation"
           (clear)="resetCalculations();"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCalculation" #selectDropdown>
</ng-select>

<input type="button" (click)="selectDropdown.handleClearClick()">
```

> This also makes sure the `resetCalculations()` being called.

Comment: This code is incomplete. It doesn't show what `resetCalculations();` contains. Which is the essential part...

Answer (score 6):

Clearing the selection can be achieved by simply setting the ngModel value to null. In the case of the above example:

```
this.selectedCalculation = null;
```

This isn't exactly the same as clicking the clear icon, as it doesn't trigger the `(clear)` output event, but it was sufficient for my needs.

Comment: Ultimately you can get **ng-select** through `@ViewChild` and call `handleClearClick` but it isn't good way since it wasn't exposed in public api methods.

Comment: @Buczkowski I would prefer your approach. The method isnt marked as private or anything Consider to add it as an answer

Comment: I am not sure, using this approach actually will not triggered ng-select (change) event

Answer (score 4):

Even thought @Buczkowski answer clears `ng-select`, it also does a focus on input, which isn't needed for all cases. So i used other method: `clearModel`

```
  // Access ng-select
  @ViewChild(NgSelectComponent) ngSelectComponent: NgSelectComponent;

  // Call to clear
  this.ngSelectComponent.clearModel();
```

So if you need to just clear input, use `clearModel` method. Else if focus and clear is needed, use `handleClearClick`.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is for clearing an input field on a specific action. I also use this code in my project according to my requirement.

In HTML write this code:

```
<ng-select [items]="products" #ngSelectComponent
           bindLabel="name"
           placeholder="Enter Product Name /SKU/ Scan Barcode"
           appendTo="body"
           name="selectedProduct"
           id="selectedProduct"
           (change)="productChange($event)"
           [multiple]="false"
           ([ngModel])="selectedProduct" >

<input type="button" (click)="clearValue()">
```

In .TS file add a `ViewChild` for this control so that if your screen consists of multiple `ngSelect` elements then you can clear a specific `ngSelect` value.

```
@ViewChild('ngSelectComponent') ngSelectComponent: NgSelectComponent;

clearValue(){
  this.ngSelectComponent.clearModel(); 
  // This line will clear the value of ngSelect control. 
  // You can write code according to your requirement.
}
```

Comment: I want to clear ngSelect after scan barcod from product

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the originally posted code sample below.

```
<ng-select class="ng-select-wrap"
           [searchFn]="multiTermSearch"
           [items]="calculationOptions"
           placeholder="Please select..."
           name="calculation"
           #calculationValue="ngModel"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCalculation">
</ng-select>
```

The `selectedCalculation` variable is created as an array and not a string, as the ng-select can allow for multiple values to be selected if `[multiple]="true"` is set.

To clear the selected value(s) in the array programmatically, use:

```
this.selectedCalculation = [];
```

Should you need to clear the bound items, use:

```
this.calculationOptions = [];
```

Both of the above can be done by adding the (change) handler in HTML.

```
(change)="change($event)
```

Something like this in your TypeScript.

```
change(event: any): void {
   this.calculationOptions = [];
   this.selectedCalculation = [];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @tim answer is correct but I will prefer you set as an empty array instead of null just to save any loop break.

```
this.selectedCalculation = [];
```

Comment: Not sure if I've misunderstood what you mean, but in this scenario `selectedCalculation` isn't an array, it's the string value (so in the screenshot `selectedCalculation` would equal `'abc'`).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @tim and @AlexOnozor,
I have successfully used 'selectedCalculation' as 'string', 'string[]', 'object[]' with Reactive Forms ( and as 'string' with ngModel ) and your suggested method worked smoothly.
I also tried using 'handleClearClick' but failed. Will update if i find my way through it.

So, this.selectedCalculation = '' or this.selectedCalculation= [] (for multipleSelect = true) should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and realised that the only thing that you need to do is to set your `calculationOptions` that you assign `[items]` to be an empty array i.e [] in your .ts file.

Now, its seems like you are asking someone set your `calculationOptions` to []. Its make sense why the `clear()` functionality does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

HTML

```
  <nz-select
        nzPlaceHolder="Select an Address"
        formControlName="addressId"
        #NzSelectAddress
      >
        <nz-option
          *ngFor="let address of addresses"
          [nzValue]="address.id"
          [nzLabel]="address.city"
        ></nz-option>
      </nz-select>
```

TS

```
@ViewChild('NzSelectAddress') NzSelectAddress: NzSelectComponent;
this.NzSelectAddress.onClearSelection();
```